# Python/Tkinter: Subclass of text widget will only display in root

Tags: python, tkinter

The code below successfully creates and displays a custom widget called "NoteBox". But it will only display in the root window, even if I create an instance and pass in the name of another window as the parent (in this case a frame). What am I missing? Any advice appreciated. Note: tkinter has been imported as tk.

```
class NoteBox(tk.Text): # is a sub-class of Text widget

    def __init__(self,parent): # pass in parent when initializing

        super().__init__()

        self["width"] = 10

        self["height"] = 10

        self["font"] = ("helvetica",12)

noteframe = tk.Frame(root,width = 500,height = 500)

noteframe.place(x=10,y=10)

# despite passing "noteframe" it displays in root window

mynote = NoteBox(noteframe) 

mynote.pack()
```

Comment: My apologies. I obviously need to understand how to format correctly on this forum.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `parent` when calling `super().__init__`

Comment: Thank you. Yes, when I add super().__init__(parent) it does work. Very odd, however, no matter what width I assign to the frame, it conforms to the width of the NoteBox custom widget. Essentially, the frame disappears. I believe I tried passing "parent" earlier, but since the frame disappears, I could not see that it was working. In any event, many thanks.